# Fuubar gem progress bar overwritten by other logs

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I included `gem fuubar` for rspec test progress.

Probably due to [this](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar/wiki/Logging), every time Fuubar progress bar is updated, almost immediately it's overwritten by other logs.

The page suggests that I should use `progressbar.log` or something to get around the issue, but I can't modify every gem for this.

What's the convention here?
You can't expect progress bar if any of the gems you use outputs log?

Comment: can you provide examples of how you're outputting from fuubar and the logs that are being output

Comment: [mcve] ... Please don't vaguely describe your problem, but provide a concrete example of what you are talking about.

Comment: **Which** gem(s) are printing to `$stdout` during the test run? (This is not generally considered normal/good behaviour!) How many? (You say "multiple", which is extra surprising.) How are they configured? (I can't suggest how to modify/reconfigure them without some basic information like this!) By what means are they printing information? `puts`, or something else?